# MS SQL Express Monitor Software

Tags: sql-server, powershell

We are looking for a tool or web application that can monitor our MS SQL Express server instances which are running on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

It should be possible to get notified when a service is not running anymore.

I can think of two levels of monitoring:

- Is the windows service in running mode? We had such situations where the Service was not started again on a Windows Startup
- Some basic connectivity check on an SQL level
- Found already some Powershell Scripts, which are useful to make connection tests. I am thinking about modifying such a script to get notified via Email when it is not available.

The should be working on a Windows Server 2012. Either free to use or commercial. It should be under active maintenance without adware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Nagios. It is free, open source, generic monitoring software.

You can monitor SQL Servers from Nagios by sensing queries and checking results, or by dedicated plugins: check_mssql_health or check_mssql.

Nagios Core and Nagwin ports work on Windows Server platform.

Comment: I heard already of Nagios years ago. I always thought that it would be good to look at it. I saw now a Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9BagdHGopg). Why nagios should die. I think it has not that good reputation.  Do you have some personal good experience with the Software?

Comment: I used Nagios and Cacti to monitor the biggest e-commerce portal in central Europe. It's ugly, but it does its job well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SysKit Monitor available here: https://www.syskit.com/products/monitor/

So basically you can configure application to watch for the windows services and if the service is stopped it will send you an alert and it will try to start the service again (if needed)

*Disclaimer: I work for the company behind this product*